# TabPage Validating event firing when clicked on the currently selected tab

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I'm doing things as said in [How do I prevent the user from changing the selected tab page in a TabControl?](http://windowsclient.net/blogs/faqs/archive/2006/05/30/how-do-i-prevent-the-user-from-changing-the-selected-tab-page-in-a-tabcontrol.aspx)

Things are working fine. But the validating event of tabpage1 occurs if I've tabpage1 is currently selected and user clicks on tabpage1 itself. and later when user clicks on tabpage2 validating event for tabpage1 doesn't fire.

What happens is if I do `e.Cancel` in validating event of tabpage1, in the above case, when user clicks on tabpage1 by mistake having tabpage1 already selected, it will prompt user that "Do you want to stay on current tab to save data or move from the current tab?". and if user clicks `Stay` but doesn't do any changes. And then when he correctly clicks tabpage2, Validating event of tabpage1 is not firing.

I've uploaded the sample application [here](https://sites.google.com/site/browsersynch/WinAppTest.zip). You can run and see the behavior to properly understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TabControl.Selecting Event` instead.

Use it like this:

```
tabControl1.Selecting += tabControl1_Selecting;

private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = !(can switch tab);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will be using Deselecting event.

Answer (score 1):

This is kinf of how validating *should* behave, it's just not a lucky match with tabpages.

You could use the Selecting/Selected events and write some more logic yourself. Or give up on either tabpages or the idea that they are to be validated individually.

Comment: No need to leave any idea nor tab page. Selecting event can do. BTW for me Deselecting event will work well. Thanks to the link given by @Jens Granlund